Unity: Set a mesh directly on the GPU
In unity I'm constructing a mesh on the GPU. Currently, I have to write the vertices / indices back to the CPU before setting them again in the mesh. This is very inefficient and takes about 90% of the total processing time.
Is there a way to take a pre-filled AppendStructuredBuffer of triangles and set those values directly on the GPU rather than writing the values back to the CPU?
Thank you
